# npm module 'openurl' not working after deploying chatbot to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, botframework

I am working on chatbot development using node.js in MS bot framework.

I need to open a webpage during the conversation. I have used `openurl` npm module which is working successfully in local environment.  After deploying to Azure from GitHub repository, the functionality is not working.

Could you please let me know any solution or fix for this?
I am also using other modules like `system-sleep` but I am facing the same problem. In short, all custom modules installed are not working after deployment to Azure.

```
var openurl = require('openurl');
var sleep = require('system-sleep');
openurl.open("https:google.com")
sleep(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

While most modules are simply plain-text JavaScript files, some modules are platform-specific binary images. These modules are compiled at install time, usually by using Python and node-gyp Azure App Service does not support all native modules and might fail at compiling those with very specific prerequisites.

the description is from [Using Node.js Modules with Azure applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/.).

Per my experience, the `system-sleep` module requires `Python` and `node-gyp` while installing.

You can try to install the modules in windows 32 platform on your local environment, and deploy your application to Azure with the node_modules folder which contains the compiled module.

On the other hand, you can leverage [Azure App Service Editor](https://developingdane.com/azure-app-service-editor/) to install those libs which are simply plain-text JavaScript files online.